# Getting request parameter data on submit

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am trying to read an input field data on click of submit on my controller.

My `login.scala.html`

```
<form action="@routes.HomeController.email_auth()" method="post">
        Enter your email address :<input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Added this to `routes`,

```
POST     /email_auth                 controllers.HomeController.email_auth
```

Reading it on `HomeController`,

```
public Result email_auth() {
        DynamicForm form = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
//        if (form.data().size() == 0) {
//            return badRequest("Expceting some data");
//        } else {
            String response = form.get("username");
            System.out.println(response);
//        }
        return ok(email_auth.render());
    }
```

Also, trying to render a different view.How to do this using java

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i see is that your route is defined as a GET request but you send your form with a post request. So Play will not find your route or take another one it can fit on your request. Your route should look like this:

```
POST     /email_auth       controllers.HomeController.email_auth
```

To render a different view you only neet to import it into your Controller and call its render method in your return method. If you want to render a view called `my_view.scala.html` you need to return `ok(my_view.render());`.

I also tried your code and the parameter gets printed to the console. So the email you want is already saved to the variable `response`.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with POST and action field. I am able to render new page now , but how do I read the input parameter on submit??

Comment: Does it print anything if you run your example or does it throw some kind of error?